# check item example application subbr pro but for my application check mp3

Tags: android

If you see `subbr pro` this application shows a folder and only file. The sSubtitles format for number items. I need this code to show the number of the folder and the number of the mp3 file for an item.
This is the source code.

```
    if(ff.isDirectory()) {
                if(ff.getName().startsWith(".")){

                }else {
                    File[] fbuf = ff.listFiles();
                    int buf = 0;
                    if (fbuf != null) {
                        buf = fbuf.length;
                    } else buf = 0;
                    String num_item = String.valueOf(buf);
                    if (buf == 0) num_item = num_item + " item";
                    else num_item = num_item + " items";
                   //String formated = lastModDate.toString();
                    dir.add(new
                            Item(ff.getName(), num_item, null, ff.getAbsolutePath(), "directory_icon"));
                }
```